# Php Error with Contact Form email received without content

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a contact form using php however when I test the form I receive an email with no content in the fields, I have checked that the fields match with the php but cannot seem to identify the problem.

The form html part of the contact page:

```
<section id="contact-page">
<div class="container">
<div class="center">        
<h2>Send us a Message</h2>
<p class="lead">Thanks for your enquiry we will respond within 24 hours. * Indicates required information</p>
</div> 
<div class="row contact-wrap"> 
<div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
<form action="sendemail2.php" method="post" id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" >
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Name *</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Email *</label>
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Phone</label>
<input type="number" name="tel"class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Company Name</label>
<input type="text" name="company" class="form-control">
</div>                        
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Subject *</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Message *</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" required class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>                        
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
</div>
</div>
</form> 
</div><!--/.row-->
</div><!--/.container-->
</section><!--/#contact-page-->
```

The Php script:

```
 <?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
    //'type'=>'success',
    //'message'=>
    'Thank you for contacting us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
);

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["name"])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["email"])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["subject"]));
    $tel = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["tel"]));
    $company = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["company"]));
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["message"])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'xxx@xxx.com';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Phone Number: ' . $tel . "\n\n" .'Company Name : ' . $company . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tested whether the form is posted or not?

Comment: You haven't checked whether form is posted or not in `sendemail2.php`
 `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` . Check this condition before you get the information from the form that you submitted.

Comment: Hi Gunaseelan, I tried echo $body; exit; placing it under the echo json_encode($status); unfortunately I get the same empty fields.

Comment: Hi, Tried both methods still have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

or use

```
<form method="post" id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" >
```

in place of

```
<form action="sendemail2.php" method="post" id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" >
```